# Forbid access to implementation file in a "real framework"

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, header, implementation

I have an iOS real framework (.framework) created with: https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework. I have only one public header, which contains the prototypes that my framework uses. For example:

frame.h

```
-(NSInteger)sum:(NSInteger)a b:(NSInteger)b;
```

frame.m

```
-(NSInteger)sum:(NSInteger)a b:(NSInteger)b{return a+b};
```

The problem starts when I link this framework to a project. It seems that only the public header can be visible and accessed, but if i set a breakpoint in the call line:

```
Framework *frame=[[Framework alloc]init];
BREAKPOINT->[frame sum:2 b:3];
```

and clicking in "**step into**" button, I can access to **frame.m** file.

How can I avoid this?

Thank you very much!